# Why do I need to specify the DB schema in a SELECT clause, when there is only one "public" schema?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am developing the database component of a small software application that connect to a PostrgreSQL 10 DB. I am reusing some code from my previous database applications, which were working perfectly fine, however much to my surprise I came across an intriguing issue. In particular, the statement:

```sql
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name>='test';
```

no longer works. Instead, I get a "*relation* table_name *does not exist*" error from Postgres.

Of course, the relation does exist and it is accessible with the user I am using for the connection.

Changing the above query to:

```sql
SELECT * FROM public."<table_name>" WHERE <column_name>='test';
```

works fine. Note that the table name **is lowercase**, and I am correctly specifying it with lowercase in the query, so case-issues are eliminated.

I have tried to set the `search_path`, as suggested by other users:

```sql
SET search_path TO public;
```

to no avail. Now I understand that it is mandatory to specify the schema name in some cases, but this was *never* the case in any of my previous DB models, moreover the first query above always worked. I don't understand why I have to prefix all the queries now in my DAO code with the schema name.

In particular, the Java code used for querying the database becomes a lot more "dirty":

```java
 String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM public.\"" + TABLE_NAME + "\" WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " = ?;";
```

What are the causes of this, and how may I avoid using the schema prefix?

Comment: something changed your `search_path`

Comment: ... or there are upper case characters in the table name, and it does not work without double quotes. Don't do that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you for your comment, but did you read my question? I wrote: "Note that the table name **is lowercase**, and I am correctly specifying it with lowercase in the query"

Comment: So `SELECT * FROM "<table_name>" WHERE <column_name>='test';` does not work either?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński That is correct.

Comment: And does that work? (note no double quotes) `SELECT * FROM public.<table_name> WHERE <column_name>='test';` If it does, what do you get from `show search_path`?

Comment: `Note that the table name is lowercase` Maybe the table was defined in (quoted) MixedCase" ? (or worse: with embedded spaces ...) From the psql-prompt try: `\d`

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Yes, `SELECT * FROM public.<table_name> WHERE <column_name>='test';` works too. `show search_path` returns `public`.

Comment: Bump, noone????